# Setting delegate for UITextField produces error

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, uitextfield

I have a table view with prototype cells and a custom table view cell class. In one of the prototype cells I have a UITextField. I'm trying to dismiss the keyboard when the return key is pressed, to do that I'm using the function `textFieldShouldReturn` and am trying to set the delegate of my UITextView to `self`(`inputText.delegate = self`). Unfortunately, without setting the delegate to self results in nothing happening when return is pressed, and with the `inputText.delegate = self` line the app crashes with the error `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`.

Here is my custom table view cell file.

```
import UIKit

class CustomTableViewCell: UITableViewCell, UITextFieldDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var inputLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var inputText: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var labelLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var labelDetail: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var picker: UIPickerView!
@IBOutlet weak var largeInputText: UITextField!

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code

    inputText.delegate = self

}

func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    print("return button in CustomTableViewCell")
    inputText.resignFirstResponder()
    return true

}

override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Means your text field isn't hooked up properly in the interface builder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There could one of these reasons because of which you are getting this error.

1. You might not have specified the class of your prototype cell in interface builder. See below

[image]

2. You might not have correctly set the IBOutlet property. Check this in last tab on the side bar shown above after clicking on the label in your prototype cell.

NOTE: Make sure that you have set the custom class for your table view controller or view controller as well.

Answer (score 0):

tryn to call awakeFromNib() from viewDidLoad() ; and then you can select what type of keyboard need for edit : inputTextFile.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.ASCIICapable/EmailAddress/etc